# Python function call in thread always returns same value

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm boggled over why a function called in a thread always returns the same value. I've confirmed that the parameters are different for each call. If I call the function after acquiring a lock then the function returns the correct value. This obviously defeats the purpose of using threads, because then this function is just called sequentially, one thread after another. Here is what I have. The function is called "get_related_properties" and I've made a note of it in the code:

```
class ThreadedGetMultipleRelatedProperties():

    def __init__(self, property_values, **kwargs):
        self.property_values = property_values
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.timeout = kwargs.get('timeout', 20)
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

    def get_result_dict(self):
        queue = QueueWithTimeout()
        result_dictionary = {}

        num_threads = len(self.property_values)
        threads = []

        for i in range(num_threads):
            t = GetMultipleRelatedPropertiesThread(queue,
                                                   result_dictionary,
                                                   self.lock)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            try:
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
            except:
                return {"Error": "Unable to process results at this time." }

        for property_value in self.property_values:
            kwargs_copy = dict.copy(kwargs)
            kwargs_copy['property_value'] = property_value
            queue.put(self.kwargs_copy)

        queue.join_with_timeout(self.timeout)

        # cleanup threads
        for i in range(num_threads):
            queue.put(None)
        for t in threads: t.join()

        return result_dictionary


class GetMultipleRelatedPropertiesThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, result_dictionary, lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.result_dictionary = result_dictionary
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        from mixpanel_helpers import get_related_properties
        while True:
            kwargs = self.queue.get()
            if kwargs == None:
                break

            current_property_value = kwargs.get('property_value')
            self.lock.acquire()
            # The function call below always returns the same value if called before acquire
            result = get_related_properties(**kwargs)
            try:
                self.result_dictionary[current_property_value] = result
            finally:
                self.lock.release()

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()
```

Here is get_related_properties, although it makes other calls, so I'm not sure the problem lives in here:

```
def get_related_properties(property_name,
                           property_value,
                           related_properties,
                           properties={},
                           **kwargs):

    kwargs['exclude_detailed_data'] = True
    properties[property_name] = property_value

    result = get_multiple_mixpanel_results(properties=properties,
                                           filter_on_values=related_properties,
                                           **kwargs)

    result_dictionary = {}
    for related_property in related_properties:
        try:
            # grab the last result here, because it'll more likely have the most up to date properties
            current_result = result[related_property][0]['__results'][0]['label']
        except Exception as e:
            current_result = None

        try:
            related_property = int(related_property)
        except:
            pass

        result_dictionary[related_property] = current_result

    return result_dictionary
```

An additional note, I've also tried to copy the function using Python's [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), both a deep and shallow copy and call the function copy, but neither of those worked.

Comment: Can you show the code for `get_related_properties`?

Comment: it looks like you're putting the same value in the queue over and over with `queue.put(self.kwargs)`.  Wouldn't this give get_related_properties the same arguments for every call?  How do you transmit 'property_value' to the thread, you pull it out of kwargs, but I don't see where you're putting it in.

Comment: Isn't it being added from the get_result_dict?

Comment: Sorry, I cleaned it up for public consumption, which resulted in the same kwargs being passed each time. I've updated the code to reflect what it's currently doing.